# Why do I get this JRE JDK error message?

Tags: java

```
Package icedtea-8-plugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'icedtea-8-plugin' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: I suspect that you're trying to install IcedTea 8, the web browser plug-in for for OpenJDK 8. If not, please [edit] your question to clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: Also see [How do I install Java?](/q/48468/175814) which includes installation instructions for IcedTea.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that **Package 'icedtea-8-plugin' has an installation candidate**, make sure that your `Software & Updates` app is set like shown below. The `multiverse` repository should be checkmarked. When you close the window, it'll ask you for permission to reload the software database... please go ahead and approve.

Then, in `terminal`, do the following to install the missing software:

*note: the `sudo apt-get update` is redundant, but it's good to be sure it got done.*

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install icedtea-8-plugin`

[image]